# How to set the color range of scatter plot so it is consistent with histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data set:

```
dat <- structure(list(
  cell_name = structure(c(
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L
  ), .Label = c("Px", "Cx", "Mx", "Ox", "OC"), class = "factor"),
   gexp = c(
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.078053491967664,
    0.0787946080465952, 0.0849179303351091, 0.0893393503333397,
    0.0904401481651504, 0.108991747968639, 0.109472235592895,
    0.120876521863314, 0.121633996276386, 0.133260178961047,
    0.141422491346724, 0.151765761772331, 0.163039227361379,
    0.181821496314555, 0.183023962970076, 0.185012779171506,
    0.190674320101334, 0.191500130355834, 0.245151812914058,
    0.251786197407558, 0.268528061492397, 0.303601828212538,
    0.33030785071184, 0.380051212059645, 0.409937261758804, 0.413185421525087
  ), sample.category = structure(c(
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
    1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
    1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
  ), .Label = c(
    "Xt.NT.0hr",
    "Xt.Saline.16hr", "Xt.Compound.16hr"
  ), class = "factor"),
  x = c(
    -6.12836877150557, -7.88484374327681, -6.18700496001265,
    -6.45607224745772, -6.91398421568892, -5.17557040495894,
    -5.00434676451704, -5.90220013899824, -5.52279416365645,
    -7.23571482939741, -4.00645772261641, -7.60095492644331,
    -6.57969895644209, -5.71780339522383, -7.29465762419722,
    -6.09494725508711, -6.92634764952681, -7.31916800780318,
    -7.69346801085493, -4.80783835692427, -5.9156226281645, -6.23338071150801,
    -6.39048472685835, -3.98181144042036, -7.35286227507613,
    -6.37823573393843, -5.96767512602827, -4.74095240874312,
    -7.12100688262007, -7.69579879088423, -7.40592185301802,
    -5.54702035231612, -7.33453170104048, -6.12831488890669,
    -7.86401644988081, -5.20023671431563, -6.26484719557783,
    -7.81010619444868, -6.60071936888716, -7.31798640532515,
    -4.35606614394209, -6.38609496397993, -7.18059436125777,
    -6.27779713912031, -7.20054999632857, -7.76712313933394,
    -5.52495375914595, -6.24379435820601, -5.23566857619307,
    -6.05110780043623, -6.87949982924483, -7.27079001708052,
    -6.85096398634932, -5.3437461022856, -3.93442956252119, -7.59850207610152,
    -7.65125361723921, -6.25943747801802, -7.33143512053511,
    -6.33743230147383, -6.08643952651045, -7.55096713347456,
    -7.11144343657515, -5.95002309126875, -6.10922948164961,
    -7.18890372557661, -7.12671843810103, -6.24059716506026,
    -4.30699292464278, -5.66289655013106, -4.80185262007735,
    -7.13948622984907, -6.67150870604536, -7.37687579436323,
    -7.78391352934859, -7.2490023736479, -5.74496260924361, -6.03136102004073,
    -7.06212893767378, -6.37314883513472, -5.33852473540327,
    -6.11003104491255, -5.68365517897627, -7.04923526091597,
    -5.93282214446089, -6.32528439803145, -4.86897603316328,
    -7.29054347319624, -7.63038436217329, -5.71889964385054,
    -6.09542743010542, -4.82401458067915, -5.97893325133345,
    -6.71384087843916, -7.20524493498823, -4.3980297212126, -4.11487237257979,
    -6.85030833525679, -6.87816754622481, -7.87402716918013,
    -5.62621775908491, -4.99655858321211, -4.66852847380659,
    -7.57268325133345, -5.39896384520552, -6.60474101347945,
    -7.77267066283247, -7.69671145720503, -5.77326957030318,
    -7.80957309050581, -4.55219546599409, -6.01630631728194,
    -5.50212136549971, -7.76106826109907, -4.21713153166792,
    -7.63483706755659, -7.89539233489058, -4.19935838027022,
    -5.78868190093062, -5.27231732649824, -6.6918529634001, -7.19847861571333,
    -6.77350703520796, -7.29259482665083, -7.66503230376265,
    -5.92225924773238, -5.94090358061812, -4.94412461562178,
    -5.27848092360518, -6.46139279646895, -4.23630992217085,
    -6.28692427916548, -5.00668660445235, -5.03211299223921,
    -7.29572287840864, -5.33259049696944
  ), y = c(
    -5.02424657839496,
    -6.71462500590045, -4.64553797739703, -4.8909190942641, -5.71065485972125,
    -4.82234514254291, -5.28217733401019, -3.866351013362, -4.37375534075458,
    -6.48378050821979, -1.45741885650117, -5.84999812144, -5.37730658549029,
    -5.34863889712054, -5.33161938685138, -4.89835823076923,
    -5.95062935847003, -4.7071119596358, -6.26194823282916, -5.22036922472674,
    -4.32524025934894, -3.79248035448749, -4.39562714594562,
    -5.28746831911761, -4.56550610560138, -5.81744492548663,
    -1.6384685088988, -2.85430014628131, -6.03716719645221, -7.30025113123614,
    -7.1568714429732, -6.01424372690875, -6.00170434015948, -3.03584480780322,
    -6.57955277460773, -4.41522968310077, -5.37504447001178,
    -6.52249014872272, -4.75782311457355, -4.62974846857745,
    -4.80379808443744, -4.52536237734515, -5.20433223742206,
    -4.70545566576678, -6.43369257944781, -6.41709864634235,
    -4.82305062311847, -2.91744268435199, -4.4250496675368, -5.37218845385272,
    -4.68633187311847, -2.56733632582385, -2.32696414488513,
    -2.86756802099902, -5.36454570788104, -6.49232972162921,
    -7.18896258372027, -5.87897027033527, -5.03146756190021,
    -3.6963902761336, -4.67556036013324, -7.27969754236896, -4.89728296297748,
    -4.84503138560016, -3.55614126223285, -2.56781030195911,
    -6.00860703486163, -2.6597498704787, -5.33996284502704, -3.27229035395343,
    -5.52028096216876, -6.94654047983844, -5.05352461832721,
    -4.85841691988666, -6.13735354441363, -2.54840064543445,
    -2.09675896662433, -4.46512854593951, -6.61105263727862,
    -6.10234320658404, -4.03706944483478, -4.91794002550799,
    -2.51595926779468, -4.77913272875506, -2.05771953362186,
    -5.00882280367572, -5.52451956766803, -6.13459790247638,
    -6.88176024454791, -5.43877637881, -4.64195335406024, -2.93488967913348,
    -4.90864980715472, -3.13988101977069, -2.98691988486011,
    -2.36754042404849, -1.61479792493541, -2.42353100079257,
    -5.22080147761066, -6.9881349851485, -2.50280356901843, -2.4409405042525,
    -5.19058645266254, -6.65987217920978, -5.1250020315047, -4.80788171786029,
    -6.56144059199054, -7.22644150751788, -5.39587510126788,
    -6.68008864420611, -3.0989873458739, -3.61012685793597, -3.17221487063129,
    -7.18178618448932, -2.10658872622211, -7.30663311976153,
    -7.09194481867511, -1.59743498015363, -2.7611458351012, -5.10656679171283,
    -2.5872366477843, -3.18813729780871, -6.07152092951495, -4.62400186556537,
    -6.3747350026961, -2.67246747511584, -6.22303259867389, -2.53317165869433,
    -2.45842046040256, -3.20620191591937, -1.96011829870898,
    -2.98910189169604, -2.67913473147113, -1.90748242038447,
    -6.58255875605304, -2.57597566145618
  ), cluster = c(
    1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1
  )
), row.names = c(NA, -136L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"))
```

I am making the histogram and scatter plot with this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)


## Making Barplot (histogram)
nbp <- ggpubr::ggbarplot(dat, x = "sample.category", y = "gexp", facet.by = "cell_name", add = "mean_se", scales = "fixed") +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, colour = "black", face = "bold")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  xlab("") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) 
nbp

## Making scatter plot (histogram)
pge <- ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, color = gexp)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.9, size = 5) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "#ededed", high = "#67000d", na.value =  "#f0f0f0") +
  facet_wrap(cell_name ~ sample.category, scales = "free", ncol = 3) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("UMAP 1") +
  ylab("UMAP 2") 
pge
```

The bar plot looks like this:

[image]

And scatter plot with color scale looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in the histogram clearly `Xt.Saline.16hr` is stronger
than `Xt.NT.0hr`. But in the scatter plot color scale we get the vivid
impression that `Xt.NT.0hr` is stronger than `Xt.Saline.16hr`.

How can I adjust the color scale in scatter plot so that it
matches the histogram?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about exactly. Your plots look correct. The Saline group may have a larger mean but it also has many fewer points than NT. The NT group has more points. It has the largest gexp values, but it also has many small values which bring down the mean. I'm not sure I understand how you want to change the plot.

Comment: In addition with what @MrFlick said, I don't thing using the color to share the information you expect is a good idea, at a methodological level. Especially when the scatterplot isn't in contradiction with the histogram

Comment: @MrFlick If you look the scatter plot, NT is clearly *redder* overall  than Saline.  That doesn't show that NT has more smaller values in scatter plot. What I want to have is to make NT less redder than Px the scatter plot.

Comment: Do you want all points in each box to the be same color (the color for the mean)? If so, you could do something like `color = ave(gexp, sample.category, FUN=mean)`

Comment: @MrFlick Maybe I misunderstand you.  You said `It's redder because it has more extreme gexp values than NT`. But if you see, it's **NT that is redder than Saline**.
Not the vice versa.


And I don't understand what you mean by `NT has 6 points greater than 0.25 while Saline only has 1.` 
No I don't want to plot the same color with mean.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the result of this: `library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = sample.category, y = gexp)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter()` and you will see that **NT** has more extreme gexp values than **Saline**. So it is expected that some points of NT appear redder. I think the underlying problem here is that barplot does not reflect distribution of your data (see [this](https://www.data-to-viz.com/caveat/boxplot.html))

Comment: @MrFlick The point is that my color scale fail to capture the small values in NT.

Comment: It does not look like it fails to me, NT has many gexp = 0 values and then it reaches gexp = 0.18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post an answer to be able to show some plots.

As remarked in the comment, your plot seems correct. However, boxplot alone might be misleading in this case.

If you add the actual points you will see that many NT points are equal to 0 and some of them peaks just above 0.4. Please, see the plot below, I have used your color scale and `geom_jitter` to show distribution of your points for the `gexp` variable.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = sample.category, y = gexp, color = gexp)) +
  # geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(.~sample.category, scale = "free_x") +
  geom_jitter() +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "#ededed", high = "#67000d", na.value =  "#f0f0f0") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]